# How to customize QDialogButtonBox buttons' background color?

Tags: qt

I have :

```
auto btnBox = new QDialogButtonBox(QFlags({QDialogButtonBox::Abort, QDialogButtonBox::Ok}));

layout()->addWidget(btnBox);
```

I tried

```
btnBox->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color : red;}");
```

But the buttons remains light gray...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Pleas add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SteveXP solution works, if you don't use QWindowsVistaStyle, which uses native drawing

Answer (score 1):

The following shorter version changes the Background-Color of the Buttons:

```
auto btnBox = new QDialogButtonBox( QDialogButtonBox::Abort| QDialogButtonBox::Ok );
layout()->addWidget(btnBox);
btnBox->setStyleSheet("background: red");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)
Sorry but it doesn't work, the buttons are still light gray here... (windows)

Comment: Just tested in a minimal code: both variants (yours and the simplified) are working fine. So theres probably something in your surrounding code. Do you set other StyleSheets for example on a parent widget? Clean-rebuild? Which Qt?

Comment: No, but the QDialogButtonBox is in a layout in a widget in a widget etc...
I tried removing all styles but the one you gave and still haven't any red :(
Even with a clean rebuild...
I'm on Qt 5.14.2

Comment: Hi, i made a minimal reproduction project, and your code works, so i tried to include more things from my big project and it appears it's my QStyle overload which induces the problem. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Ok ve've found the culprit : QWinfowsVistaStyle just defers the buttons drawing to windows, so the QPalette is not handled...